# Cypress doesn't find Environment variable from cypress.env.json

Tags: testing, error-handling, automation, environment-variables, cypress

I have the following folder structure:

```
tests
  cypress.env.json
  cypress
    fixtures
    integration
      test
        test.spec.ts
    plugins
    support
```

I have missed out the for the question unnecessary files.
So my cypress.env.json looks like this:

```js
{
  "loginTestStage": {
    "admin": {
      "username": "value1",
      "password": "value2"
    },
    "user": {
      "username": "value3",
      "password": "value4"
    }
  },
  "vatid" : {
    "x1": "value5",
    "x2": "value6",
    "x3": "value7",
    "x4": "value8"
  }
}
```

Now I try to access the env variable in the test.spec.ts file:

```js
describe('Login', () => {
    const usernameInput = '[formcontrolname="username"]';
    const passwordInput = '[formcontrolname="password"]';
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit(url)
    })

    it('Allow users with valid credentials to login', () => {
        const { username, password } = Cypress.env('loginTestStage').admin;
        cy.get(usernameInput).type(username);
        cy.get(passwordInput).type(password);
        ...

    })
})
```

When I try to run the test I always get this error here:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'admin')
```

So the value from the Env variable can't be found.
How can this be solved?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will work if you move `cypress.env.json` to the project root.

Just like `cypress.config.js` (v10) or `cypress.json` (v9) there is no configuration path for this `env` file, it is assumed to be at the project root.

Comment: it is already  in the same root as the cypress.json. Where exactly is the project root?

Comment: Above you show it in the `tests` folder. When I moved it up a level, the `Cypress.env('loginTestStage').admin` where correctly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

To make Cypress.env() work on Cypress 12.17.2, I had to put my environment variables into the `cypress.config.ts` file (which is on the **root of the project, not the root of the Cypress directory**).

See docs: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#No-Arguments

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  env: {
    foo: 'bar',
    baz: 'quux',
  },
})
```

Comment: Further info about `cypress.env.json` can be found here [Option #2: cypress.env.json](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-2-cypressenvjson)

Comment: Thanks @Feldeisen, I actually did that but it did not work in my case. Maybe the file was not in the correct hierarchy, but I moved it around and couldn't make it work.

Comment: Rest assured it does work - now also in Cypress 13.

Comment: It is it possible to pass `process.env.foo` to foo because I got undefined.